# Reopen deleted questions

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, vote-to-reopen

What happens if a deleted question is nominated for reopening by 5 users?

Why can we vote for reopening if the question is deleted?

> [image]

(I voted for reopening after the question was deleted. Just for testing.)

Let's test it together [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22812730/1420197).

Comment: That works, it has now 2 reopen votes

Comment: @rene 3, 2 votes more! I am very curious.

Comment: It doesn't seem to appear in the reopen queue so that is good :-)

Comment: It might get reopened, but it will remain deleted.

Comment: @Oded Yeps, it [was](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22812730/1420197). :-)